# Getting position within K-Means cluster

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm clustering a set of 5000 images using K-Means, and moving them to folders according to cluster number. Is there a way to leverage the clustering to order them by similarity within each directory?

One solution I thought of is calculating the distance (with annoy) between a random image and all others in a cluster/folder, and adding an incremental index to the filename so they are sorted by visual proximity.

I wonder if there's already a subproduct of the clustering I could use for this. Distance from the cluster centroid wouldn't work since two samples could have similar distances but in different directions, so I'm thinking something like the distance to origin in a 2D scatterplot?

Comment: Interesting task. My intuition is that if you sort by distance to origin you kind of sort by brightness, while sorting by distance to centroid is sorting by the images closest to the "average image in the cluster". So, what "concept" do you wish to sort by?

Comment: The second option sounds more like what I'm trying to do, but then again wouldn't samples that are equally different from the average image, but in opposite directions, end up together?

Comment: True, but that could also happen with sorting by distance to origin, right? In the context of clustering I would think that the difference between close and far for centroids is more interesting than brightness. I don't think there is anything wrong with having two equally close points to the origin, the sorting would just be ambiguous to them. Also, it is highly improbable to end up with two equally spaced points like that with real data (not that it would be a problem anyways).

Comment: @NaphatAmundsen I ended up clustering each cluster again, only renaming the files with cluster index instead of creating subfolders. After playing with the parameters, I reached a rather satisfactory result this way. Duplicates end up in the same cluster, and similar views are grouped since they end up in neighbouring clusters too